# Naming the clusters in silhouette plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

I am trying to name the clusters in the silhouette plot. Can some one suggest how i can name each silhouette cluster?

```
library(cluster)
data(ruspini)
pr4 <- pam(ruspini, 4)
str(si <- silhouette(pr4))
plot(si, col = c("red", "yellow", "blue", "purple"))# with cluster-wise coloring
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't be changed since the names on the plot are values from the column `cluster` in `si` which is a matrix with doubles. If you would coeerce this column, whole matrix would coerce to type `character` and then the `plot` function for `silhouette` object would not work.

```
library(cluster)
data(ruspini)
pr4 <- pam(ruspini, 4)
str(si <- silhouette(pr4))
plot(si, col = c("red", "yellow", "blue", "purple"))# 
typeof(si)
si
```